# image not show on yii mpdf,

Tags: php, yii

i used mpdf to generate report on yii. when i want to generate a report, my image header not show like usuall. my image change like this :

[image]

how can it happens? yesterday i think it run normally
i check it is on right path. i think when image path not right, it should be like this image right ?

[image]

any ideas to solve my problems?

thankyou in advance,,,,

code for get header :

```
    $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
    $html = '<table width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="70%" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
                        This is title
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%" style="text-align:right">
                ((here is image not show))      <img width="100px" src="'.$baseUrl.'/images/logos.jpg"> ((here is image not show))
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align:center;">
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>        
                    <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;"></td>
                    <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>';

    return $html;
```

Comment: you use img or somethings others ... show related code

Comment: yes, i used image. i have googling and have related issue about html encode?

Comment: try using a div with  background img

Comment: I have posted and answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using style = background-image

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$html = '<table width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td width="70%" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
                    This is title
                </td>
                <td width="30%" 
                    style="text-align:right" style="width: 100px; 
                       background-image: url('" .$baseUrl.'/images/logos.jpg ."')">
                </td>
 .......
```

and be sure the url resulting is correct ..

and for https management you  use

```
Url::to(['post/index'], 'https');


<td width="30%" 
                style="text-align:right" style="width: 100px; 
                   background-image: url('" .
                           Url::to(['/images/logos.jpg'], 'https') . "')">
            </td>
```

Remember of add  `use yii\helpers\Url;` and eventually var_dump the result for adjusting properly path and quote ..

Comment: i copy paste your code, and get notice like this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' on line 16

Comment: then i fix the code like this : <td width="30%" 
                    style="text-align:right" style="width: 100px; background-image: url("'.$baseUrl.'/images/logos.jpg") ">
      </td>

Comment: but i still dont get an image

Comment: hi @scaisEdge, i know the problem. on my case, my application running on https, but when print into pdf, baseurl change into http, so image doesn't appear. do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I have update the answer  ... could be helpers\Url  is ueful

Comment: the problem is my web using https and the image url still http, so i have a solution, i changed my baseUrl into : $baseUrl = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); to get https url. then all work as i expected. thankyou for your response scaisEdge

Answer (score 2):

**it is working as of now. Hope this will help you.**

**Solution** : Try relative path of image instead of URL. Image must be hosted on the same server.

Try this : `$baseUrl = Yii::$app->basePath` instead of `$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;`

**OR**

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html= "<img src='basePath here' alt=''>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->debug = true; 
$output = $mpdf->Output();
```